# Jquery - how to get jquery object of checkbox that are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to ask how to get Jquery object of checkboxes that are checked.

I have several checkboxex that have "checkboxes" class.
some are checked, and some others are not checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" checked="checked" />
```

I put $('.checkboxes') into checkboxes variable.

```
var checkboxes = $('.checkboxes');
```

But I don't know what to write after this.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: get all selected. var checkValues = $('input[class=checkboxes]:checked');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has a selector for checked or selected items: [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/). So to get all checked checkboxes into an object use this:

```
var checkedBoxes = $( '.checkboxes:checked' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.checkboxes').click(function() {
        alert($(this).val() + ' ' + (this.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'));
    });
});
```